# how to build any dnn website source code in Visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dotnetnuke

I have received source code of dnn website of some product from the client. And when i tried to open in Visual studio 2010, it's giving some build errors but when we hit the url , it's running fine. Could you please tell me how can i build the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "build" the website for DNN, you'll only be building Modules and Providers if you need to make any changes.

Comment: So, if i want to see the flow of application or want to add code in the application. Can't we do that? Is there any way to build the application or not?

Comment: You will need to download the SOURCE package for DNN and work on that, but you will be far better off never doing that and working on modules themselves. As soon as you try to customize DNN you're forked and will likely get so far off that you can never get back to the original open source upgrades